# Banner ad with 'slidedown' function working in my jsfiddle but not real environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working with a banner ad and the jquery slidedown function.

My desired goal is to simply have the banner slide down after several seconds and cover up the header of my page, until the user either completes the form (or clicks the "x", which I haven't placed yet.

I got it working just fine within the jsfiddle environment, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why it will not "slide down" in my live environment.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tXumG/13/.

Here is the banner on my live page: http://online.saintleo.edu/the-saint-leo-experience/faculty-spotlights.aspx

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  Thank you very much.

```
HTML:

<div class="hidden">
    <body>
  <div id="blog-subscribe-outer-container">
    <div id="blog-subscribe-overlay">
        <div id="blog-subscribe-left"><img src="http://online.saintleo.edu/media/150491/blog-logo-

icon.png" /></div>
        <div id="blog-subscribe-center"><span style="color: #FF0000; font-family: arial; font-size: 

35px">Subscribe Now!</span></div>
        <div id="blog-subscribe-right">
            <script charset="utf-8" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/current.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({ 
    portalId: '206683',
    formId: '3c8d4d75-6e0e-4d1a-a39d-c2728223e2d9'
  });
</script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="blog-subscribe-base">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</div>

----------------------------

JS:

jQuery(function($) {
    $('.hidden').delay(4000).slideDown("slow");
});

-----------------------------

CSS:

.hidden {
    display: none
}
#blog-subscribe-outer-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#blog-subscribe-overlay {
    background-color: orange;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#blog-subscribe-base {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #275d39;
}

#blog-subscribe-left {
    float:left;
}

#blog-subscribe-center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top: 45px;
}

#blog-subscribe-right {
    float:right;
    width: 33%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#blog-subscribe-inner-container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: It looks as though you do not have a reference to JQuery. http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Hi imtheman, thank you for taking the time to help me.  I am very new at this so excuse my ignorance. Do I simply add a reference above the other script,  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.blog-subscribe-hidden').delay(4000).slideDown("slow");
});
</script>     because I tried and it didn't work. I may be doing it wrong.

Comment: I see it there now. Another thing, you cannot have a `div` element outside of your `body` tag. Also, all of your `script` tags would probably be better off in the `head` section.

Comment: Thank you, again, imtheman.  I appreciate your kindness and the great tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use Css Transitions

And Then use jquery to add the class to element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.blog-subscribe-hidden').addClass('animated');
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tXumG/14/

Comment: user3080247 - thank you SO much!  This did the trick.  The only thing that I had to add was a z-index to the .animated CSS.  You're great, thank you again.